# HOW to do Load testing using gatling for 10000 QPS

Tags: load-testing, gatling

gatling is great tool for load testing..
While exploring it how we can extend and do Load testing using gatling for 10000 QPS?
Simple scenario like for 1 hour 10000QPS for given exec scenarios.
Can someone suggest injection pattern to use?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like

```
setUp(
  scn.inect(
    constantUsersPerSec(10000) during (1 hour)
  )
)
```

all in the documentation